# Scroll on mobile stops Vue.js click events from firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, scroll, vuejs2

Vue.js click events do not fire when the page has even been slightly scrolled on mobile. This applies to both Chrome and Safari on iPhone. Click events still work if they are clicked and the page isn't moved, but as soon as it is scrolled (even slightly), they cease to work.

I've tried adding `cursor: pointer;` to my CSS, and I've tried removing different plugins and functions. I've tried running a production build as well. However nothing works.

It seems like a very strange issue, and it appears across two different pages but only on mobile. I haven't been able to find any examples of this happening to anyone else before. I have a lot of code, so difficult to know what to put here also.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your Vue.js event code might help

Comment: There are multiple click events across 5/6 JS files, and they all don't fire. So not sure what code that I could post would be most helpful :/...